# iOS: Are there any pitfalls using keychain to save data

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I am saving an important key in the iOS `keychain`. Everything seems to be working okay right now. There has only been only one issue. The keychain data is still alive after you delete the App. Which I was able to resolve by checking if the App has just been installed and deleting the data in the keychain. However, I want to be sure if there isn't any more issues or pitfalls I should be looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apple keychain uses 256 bit AES encryption to secure data. It is ostensibly the mechanism that Apple uses internally to store private data such as your passwords as well. Other than your comment about the data being persisted after you delete your app (which is a feature not a bug), there’s not going to a “gotcha” when using the keychain API. Just realize that the keychain is just a fancy encrypted database, and follow best practices for what you should store, and when you access / write to it, like any other DB.